# Bispectrum vs cyclic spectrum

Tags: power-spectral-density

One of the definitions of the cyclic spectrum is
$$S^\alpha_x\left(f\right)=\lim_{\Delta f \rightarrow 0}\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\Delta t}\int_{-\Delta  t/2}^{\Delta  t/2}\Delta f X_{1 / \Delta f}\left(t, f + \frac{\alpha}{2}\right)X_{1 / \Delta f}^*\left(t, f - \frac{\alpha}{2}\right)dt$$

where $X_{1 / \Delta f}\left(t, f\right)$ is the complex envelope of the narrow-band-pass of $x(t)$ with a center frequency of $f$ and approximate bandwidth of $\Delta f$ is defined as:

$$X_{1 / \Delta f}\left(t, f\right)=\int_{t-\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}^{t+\frac{1}{2\Delta f}}x(u)e^{-2\pi j f u}du$$.

Based on Wikipedia, the definition of the bispectrum is $$B(f_{1},f_{2})=X(f_{1})\cdot X(f_{2})\cdot X^{*}(f_{1}+f_{2})$$ where
$X$ denotes the Fourier transform of the signal $x(t)$.

While the cyclic spectrum is intended for the decomposition of amplitude modulation signals, it is not clear to me what the bispectrum is used for. Moreover, how the difference in the definitions contributes to the differences in their properties?

Comment: Oh dear.  This could be cleaned up a bit.  Gideon, I might suggest not conflating $f$ in the top equation with $f_1$ or $f_2$ in the bottom equation.  If you want to express frequency in Hz (what we call *"ordinary frequency"* as opposed to *"angular frequency"*), then don't use $f$ for a function.  Also no reason to reciprocate $\Delta f$ in the subscript of $X(\cdot)$.

Comment: This is performing a form of autocorrelation on the spectrum $X(\cdot)$.  This is to show  the degree of periodicity in the spectrum.  The more periodic the spectrum is, the more that the time-domain data appears to be sampled.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, can you please send me a reference to your expectation? I am looking for a little bit more details...

Comment: The bispectrum can be used to identify the presence of nonlinear properties of systems. Nonlinearities commonly exhibit energy at frequencies that are the sum or difference of systems with multiple resonance/excitation frequencies.